# SQL 2000 INCORECT SYNTAX NEAR WITH

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using this code:

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT panelname FROM inventorypanelcaptions UNION ALL SELECT CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(50)) FROM INVENTORYPANELCAPTIONS) SELECT CASE WHEN  cast(min(right(panelname, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) < 10 THEN 'o0' ELSE 'o' END + cast(min(right(panelname, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) FROM cte WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT panelname FROM inventorypanelcaptions WHERE right(inventorypanelcaptions.panelname, 2)= right(cte.panelname, 2)+1) ", con);
```

I'm getting incorrect syntax near 'With'

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server and the code should work.

Comment: Isn't there any possible way doing this?

Comment: CTEs were added with SQL Server 2005. You'll need to upgrade at least that far for this query to run. Additionally, both Sql Server 2000 and Sql Server 2005 are now **end of life**. They no longer get _**any**_ patches or updates... not even critical security updates. It's irresponsible and dangerous to continue using them; upgrading to a supported database should be your first priority here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work in SQL 2000, you can move it to a subquery

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  cast(min(right(panelname, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) < 10 THEN 'o0' ELSE 'o' END + cast(min(right(panelname, 2) + 1) as varchar(50)) 
    FROM (
        SELECT panelname FROM inventorypanelcaptions UNION ALL SELECT CAST(0 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
        FROM INVENTORYPANELCAPTIONS
    ) cte 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT panelname 
                        FROM inventorypanelcaptions 
                        WHERE right(inventorypanelcaptions.panelname, 2)= right(cte.panelname, 2)+1
                     ) ", con);
```

Comment: More precisely, this is a derived table.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a distinction.